# I have a array of hash in which I have user name and price and I wants to retrieve uniq order

Tags: ruby

I have array of hash

```
[{"user"=>"a1", "drink"=>"d1", "price"=>"60"}, 
 {"user"=>"a2", "drink"=>"d2", "price"=>"30"}, 
 {"user"=>"a3", "drink"=>"d3", "price"=>"30"}, 
 {"user"=>"a2", "drink"=>"d4", "price"=>"40"}]
```

I want unique result by user and combine it with price

```
[{"user"=>"a1", "drink"=>"d1", "price"=>"60"},
 {"user"=>"a2", "drink"=>"d2", "price"=>"70"}, 
 {"user"=>"a3", "drink"=>"d3", "price"=>"30"}
]
```

Comment: “I want result”—developers code when they want results.

Comment: @Ilya can u please more elaborate bcoz m new in ruby

Comment: Did you try to read docs?

Comment: Yes, I read and not sure how to implement it. can u plz help it out, if u can

Comment: https://rubymonk.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [{"user"=>"a1", "drink"=>"d1", "price"=>"60"},
 {"user"=>"a2", "drink"=>"d2", "price"=>"30"},
 {"user"=>"a3", "drink"=>"d3", "price"=>"30"},
 {"user"=>"a2", "drink"=>"d4", "price"=>"40"}]

 b = []

 a.each_with_object({}) do |x|
    count =  b.find {|y| y["user"] == x["user"] }
    if count.nil?
        b << x
    else
        count["price"] = count["price"].to_i + x["price"].to_i
        count["price"] = count["price"].to_s
    end
 end

puts b
```

Comment: You are abusing `each`. It should be `b = a.each_with_object([]) {...}`.